# Goroutines listening for the same result on a channel

Tags: go, goroutine

I currently have multiple goroutines of the same function that need to wait at some point in their execution for a result from a separate part of the program before continuing. My first thoughts would be to have a channel for each of the goroutines and then once we get the result, we iterate over all channels, write into them and close after?

How do I 'share' the result with the goroutines effectively/efficiently? Is the only way to write to their respective channels that they're listening/blocked on before moving on with the next part of their execution? Seems a bit excessive.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So I understand that your waiting goroutines need a value returned by some other goroutine?

Answer (score 1):

Use channel close to coordinate multiple goroutines waiting on an event.

Here's an example. The `printer` function represents the goroutines waiting on a result. The first argument is a channel that will be closed after the result is set. The second argument is a pointer to the result.

```
func printer(ready chan struct{}, result *string) {
    <-ready
    fmt.Println(*result)
}
```

Use it like this:

```
ready := make(chan struct{})
var result string

// Start the goroutines.

go printer(ready, &result)
go printer(ready, &result)

// Set the result and close the channel to signal that the value is ready.

result = "Hello World!"
close(ready)
```

This works because receive on a closed channel returns the zero value of the channel's type.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M3bxObMCIf9)

Comment: Would context be a better alternative than a channel? I know a context also uses a channel but context would also allow passing request scoped variables along with better control (timeouts, deadlines, a cancel function etc).

Comment: @masnun The `ready` channel is the simpler and more direct solution to the problem as stated in the question.  It's trivial to add timeout/deadline and cancel.  It may that context is the better alternative given the broader scope fo the OP's program, but nothing in the question suggests that the extra complexity is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a channel to send the result to each goroutine, you can store the result to a shared variable, and use a condition variable to broadcast that the result is ready, so all goroutines can read it from the shared variable.

Something like this:

```
var resultVar *ResultType // resultVar = nil means result not ready
var c sync.Cond // initialize this before using it

func f() {
  // compute result
  c.L.Lock()
  resultVar = result
  c.L.Unlock()
  c.Broadcast()
}

func goroutine() {
  ...
  c.L.Lock()
  for resultVar == nil {
    c.Wait()
  }
  c.L.Unlock()
}
```